# After merged files image color changed from white on red

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I have an issue with importing page from one PDF file to another. Some colors from source PDF changes to red (see images below).

Input:

[image: Input]

Output:

[image: Output]

This is the source file: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lIbcg70VPQP8dLjBJ4oXp0BNtLNu48Ns/view?usp=sharing)

This is the PDF merge code that I use:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using Matrix = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix;
using Rectangle = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle;

namespace MergePdf
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MergeFilesToPdf(@"C:\input.pdf", @"C:\output.pdf");
        }

        private static void MergeFilesToPdf(string sourseFilePath, string targetFilePath)
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(targetFilePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (var document = new Document())
                {
                    using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs))
                    {
                        document.Open();

                        ImportFile(document, writer, sourseFilePath);

                        document.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void ImportFile(Document document, PdfWriter writer, string sourseFilePath)
        {
            using (var reader = new PdfReader(sourseFilePath))
            {
                for (var i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    var documentPageSizeWidthPt = Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(200);
                    var documentPageSizeHeightPt = Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(200);
                    document.SetPageSize(new Rectangle(documentPageSizeWidthPt, documentPageSizeHeightPt));
                    document.NewPage();

                    Rectangle imageSizePt = reader.GetPageSize(i);
                    SizeF resizedSizePt = new SizeF(500, 300);

                    PdfImportedPage imp = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                    var tm = new Matrix();
                    var x = (documentPageSizeWidthPt - resizedSizePt.Width) / 2;
                    var y = (documentPageSizeHeightPt - resizedSizePt.Height) / 2;

                    tm.Scale(resizedSizePt.Width / imageSizePt.Width, resizedSizePt.Height / imageSizePt.Height, MatrixOrder.Append);
                    tm.Translate(x, y, MatrixOrder.Append);

                    writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(imp, tm.Elements[0], tm.Elements[1], tm.Elements[2], tm.Elements[3], tm.Elements[4], tm.Elements[5]);
                }
                writer.FreeReader(reader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use iText7, but the issue did not go away. Can you help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is that already your source file contains the red drawing, it merely by default is not shown as the red drawing is in an optional content group (aka "Layer" in Adobe Acrobat) which starts invisible:

*Layer with red disabled*

[image: Screenshot, disabled layer]

*Layer with red enabled*

[image: Screenshot, enabled layer]

iText page import does not fully support optional content group copying, so the whole content including the red drawing is visible in your page copy.

To make sure your copy does not show any unexpected content, you should remove the content of such optional content groups from your source files and not merely disable the groups.